# android libuv use of undeclared identifier 'EPOLL_CLOEXEC'

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, libuv, bionic

i'm trying to build libuv for android in android studio cmake and i get the following errors:

> error: use of undeclared identifier 'EPOLL_CLOEXEC'
>
> warning: implicit declaration of function 'epoll_pwait' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
>
> warning: this function declaration is not a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]

how can i fix this?
am i supposed to use libuv toolchain to build it?

Comment: "error: use of undeclared identifier EPOLL_CLOEXEC'" <-- include the proper header that declares EPOLL_CLOEXEC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is probably that your `minSdkVersion` is too low. That wasn't supported until Android L. Unfortunately because some other popular projects misused that constant to detect if `epoll_create1` was available, the constant is not available until `epoll_create1` is. See https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/394 for more details.

Comment: you totally right. as i changed the min api level to 21 and linked with 'atomic' it got built successfully.